# storing bounce notifications in database

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

I want to get the error code and the bounced mail when a bounce occurs.

I have added content filter below bounces in `master.cf` and created a piping. I created a transport map in `main.cf` and I specified `gmail.com` and called the piping.

Now this code works but it treats all the gmail ids as bounce and storing it in database and mail is not getting delivered even if I specify a correct mail address. I want the transport map to be called only when a bounce condition occurs and store those parameters into my database.

So instead of `gmail.com` what should I specify to get my query solved?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not only not supported, but isn't how email works in actual fact.

What is the REAL problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: if i send a mail and if the mail bounces then i have to get that bounced mail id and the status id and store it in database.

Comment: if u want will post my codes..